# Getting started with kubernetes and fabric8

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8

I have so far worked on `Docker for Windows`. I got to know about what Docker is, how containers and services are created and how it is useful for a longer run.

Now, I am introduced with `Kubernetes` and `Fabric8`. I looked thorough the internet for learning about it. But comparitively it is a fresher thing.

I know articles might be available online for getting to know about it; but what I am looking for is -

- some basic, introductory layman details about these two.
- a few links for links for working on these in **Windows**.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: was the answer helpful @Trivedi ?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes is an open-source container orchestrator that automates deployment, scaling, and management of containerized applications, achieving high levels of hardware utilisation.
It groups containers that make up an application into logical units for easy management and discovery.

It has an API where you store some JSON objects describing how you want your applications to ran, and Kubernetes takes care of the rest.

The easiest way to start with Kubernetes is through Minikube, which allows you to have a kubernetes cluster on your local computer using a virtual machine.

Here you can find some links on how to use minikube on Windows:

- [Getting Started with Kubernetes on your Windows Laptop with Minikube](https://rominirani.com/tutorial-getting-started-with-kubernetes-on-your-windows-laptop-with-minikube-3269b54a226)
- [Running your own Docker images in minikube for windows](https://medium.com/@maumribeiro/running-your-own-docker-images-in-minikube-for-windows-ea7383d931f6)

Fabric8 is a platform thought to make it easy to deploy applications on kubernetes. So instead of talking directly to the Kubernetes API, you use fabric8 interface to describe how you want to run your applications. This platform makes it easy to use Kubernetes, providing an opinionated way of using Kubernetes.
The best place to start has to be [its own documentation] (https://fabric8.io/gitbook/overview.html), which contains notes on [how to install it on Windows](https://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/gofabric8.html#prerequisites).